# Hyperlink in datagrid view

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to set hyperlink field in datagrid view. When user clicks on that link, a query string should be generated and user should be directed to another page. So how can I set hyperlink to generate query string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do like...

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink ID="Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("DataKeyName", "~/View.aspx?Id={0}") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 9):

```
<asp:GridView ID="Griddata" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="1"
                GridLines="Horizontal" Width="1000px" ShowFooter="True" CssClass="grid"   AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="ID" DataTextField="rec_id" DataNavigateUrlFields="rec_id"
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="followme.aspx?record={0} " />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Login" DataField="LoginName"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is a sample GridView defined in ASP.NET 
You need to specify the `<asp:Hyperlinkfield>`  in the column definition.

In that field, you need to specify the `DataTextfield` (is what will be displayed on screen in that column), your `URL` (`DataNavigateUrlFormatString`) and your parameter that you want to use in that `URL` (`DataNavigateUrlFields`)

**Note:** I'm binding to this grid from code-behind, not through a `SqlDatAdaptor` but the result is the same.

You will get something like this:

[image: sample bound URL]

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href='page.aspx?id=<#Eval("ID")>'>click</a>
```